# Django Form Not Saving the Data

Tags: python, django

I've imported this `from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm`
used `csrf_token` in the **form** but still when I hit **submit** the page reloads but doesn't save the data to database.

```py
def signup(req):
    if req.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(req.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    form = UserCreationForm()
    reg_con={
        'regform': form
    }
    return render(req, 'signup.html', reg_con)
```

**form**

```html
<form action="." method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ regform.as_ul }}
    <input type="submit" value="Sign Up">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normally because something is wrong with your form the problem is however that you each time construct a *new* form, and you thus can not see what went wrong. You should only create a new form in case it is a GET request, so:

```
def signup(req):
    if req.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(req.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
    reg_con={
        'regform': form
    }
    return render(req, 'signup.html', reg_con)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `action` attribute from your `form` tag. Also don't forget to redirect after calling `form.save()`